# How to expand bound & styled TreeViewItem nodes

Tags: wpf, silverlight, treeview, styles

I have a TreeView in WPF which I have bound to a collection of categories that itself contains a collection of categories and son on and so forth. Currently, I'm binding the collection successfully and having all of my category names appearing. However, I also have an IsExpanded property on my collection objects that when all set to true only expand the first TreeViewItem but no subsequent ones.

Does anyone know what may be wrong with my TreeView styles?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="menuHierarchicalTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" >          
        <Border x:Name="treeViewItemBorder"
                CornerRadius="3"
                MinWidth="125" 
                BorderBrush="Silver" Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Height="24" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="treeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCategories}"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource menuHierarchicalTemplate}" >                              
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>                                
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Height="24" FontSize="12" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>                                
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>                            
                    </TreeViewItem>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>

<TreeView Name="menuTreeView"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="10"   
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource treeViewItemStyle}">                
</TreeView>
```

Thanks,

Xam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the "treeViewItemStyle" only to the first level of items in the TreeView.  You have to set it as well as the ItemContainerStyle of the TreeViewItems.  So, in your ControlTemplate, you'll need something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <TreeViewItem ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource treeViewItemStyle}".../>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Better yet, you can just remove the "x:Key" attribute in your Style declaration.  Doing so will automatically apply the style to **all** TreeViewItems.

*SIDE NOTE:*

I would suggest that instead of overriding the ControlTemplate like what you did above, just use property Setters in the Style instead.  Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SubCategories}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource menuHierarchicalTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Height="24" FontSize="12" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It's quite unusual to use the same Control as part of the ControlTemplate of itself (i.e. using TreeViewItem in the ControlTemplate of a TreeViewItem).

Comment: Thanks for your great response. Unfortunately, the XAML parser won't let me apply the same style recursively to many ItemContainerStyle attributes. Your idea of just using setters was good, but because of issues with selecting items I have to use the template I already have. It seems the only way I can get around all of this is to create the same TreeViewItem style many times each with different names in order to expand a deeper hierarchy. This is bad as it will artificially limit the  depth to which I can expand each TreeViewItem node. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: When I use your side note approach, I always get an exception that states, "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first".

Comment: re:  exception.  you're probably getting it because you're setting the TreeViewItem.Header property on both the style and the HierarchicalDataTemplate.  Try to remove one of them and see if it works.